# Can I compile Java code with Android makefile

Tags: java, android, makefile, sdk, android-ndk

I'm investigate about Android makefile. Here are the code and Android.mk

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
------------------------------------------------
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= \
        hello.cpp
LOCAL_MODULE:= hello
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

In command line i run $ndk-build --> generate executable file. It successfully.

Then my project leader ask me about using Android makefile with Java source code. I create Main.java and Android.mk. I replace hello.cpp with Main.java then $ndk-build. But it doesn't work.

Could anyone help me the Android.mk file what command line should i use?
--------------------------Other question-------------------------------------

```
"The Android NDK is a set of tools that allows Android application developers to embed native machine code compiled from C and/or C++ source files into their application packages".
```

When I use source with .c or .cpp, then run ndk-build to compile executable or library file. As I understand, for java source code, we need other tool SDK/JDK to compile.

But can I use Android makefile to compile Java code, are there any command like jdk-build? Do I need use JNI moethod in Java source code? Because if I generate Java codeonly, then run $ndk-build. it generate output file but there is warning

```
Android NDK: Unsupported source file extension
```

Comment: The AOSP toolchain used for building Android itself does have some makefiles for building Java libraries, but those are not present in the NDK as far as I know. Does your project leader have any particular reason for not wanting to use the standard way of using Gradle for building Android apps?

Comment: @Michael Thank for your response. Since I practice about Android Makefile and PL just ask the question "Android makefile can compile Java code or not"? This is just a question, but I want to practice to build a simple application. I know there is some Android.mk for java source code, but don't know how to execute it? (maybe not ndk-build)